# What is the purpose of the -nodes argument in openssl?

Tags: openssl

What is the purpose of the `-nodes` argument in openssl?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I disagree, openssl is a low-level toolkit and developers have to deal with it all the time.  The line is fairly blurry, and it would be a big loss to not allow openssl questions here simply because it happens to be a CLI rather than the C lib.

Comment: @gtd - that's a frequent complaint when I flag these. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306). (But I think I made a mistake on this one - the question is from 2011, and I believe its was on-topic back then. I don't like to penalize for the policy change).

Comment: @gtd - re: *"openssl is a low-level toolkit and developers have to deal with it all the time."* - that's what [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) are for. *"... it would be a big loss to not allow openssl questions ..."* - openssl C programming questions are always welcomed here. The loss of the non-programming questions will not be missed because Stack Overflow is a programming and development site. There's other sites to go to when you don't know how to use a command.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll post my response there since I think this is a very important issue.

Answer (score 175):

The option `-nodes` is not the English word "nodes", but rather is "no DES".  When given as an argument, it means OpenSSL will not encrypt the private key in a [PKCS#12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12) file.

To encrypt the private key, you can omit `-nodes` and your key will be encrypted with 3DES-CBC.  To encrypt the key, OpenSSL prompts you for a password and it uses that password to generate an encryption key using the key-derivation function [EVP_BytesToKey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html).

Depending on your version of OpenSSL and compiled options, you *may* be able to provide these options in place of `-nodes`:

```
-des          encrypt private keys with DES
-des3         encrypt private keys with triple DES (default)
-idea         encrypt private keys with idea
-seed         encrypt private keys with seed
-aes128, -aes192, -aes256
              encrypt PEM output with cbc aes
-camellia128, -camellia192, -camellia256
              encrypt PEM output with cbc camellia
```

Ultimately at the library level OpenSSL calls the function [PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/PEM_read_X509.html) with the encryption algorithm (or lack thereof) you choose.

Comment: By encrypt, do you mean with a password?

Comment: @Flimm: Protected with a password, yes.  The password generates an encryption key using a key-derivation algorithm, and the encryption is done with the key, not the password.  The only way to use the encrypted key is to decrypt it first, for which you need to know the password it was encrypted with to generate the same key.

Comment: why shoulud I encrypt my private key file? those arent published to anyone, hence the name. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Blauhirn:  You'd encrypt your private key file for the same reason you'd encrypt any file: you don't want someone who obtains a copy to be able to read it or use it.  Whether you should encrypt the private key depends on the importance of the key and your threat model.

Answer (score 16):

**edit:** nginx v1.7.3 has added an [**ssl_password_file**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file) directive which reads passphrases from a specified file trying each passphrase on the context's *encrypted-private.key*

indiv is correct that the `-nodes` argument means that OpenSSL will create UNencrypted *private.key*; otherwise, there will be a passphrase prompt to create *encrypted-private.key*. see [req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html#item__nodes), [pkcs12](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#item__nodes), [CA.pl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/CA.pl.html#item__newreq_nodes)

however, I feel the *purpose* (for programmers) is because:

- HTTP servers (e.g. [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#removepassphrase), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)) cannot read *encrypted-private.key* without passphrase →

  - Option A - each time HTTP server starts, must provide passphrase for *encrypted-private.key*
  - Option B - specify `ssl_password_file file.keys;` in `http { }` or `server { }` context. [[ref](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file)]
  - Option C - use `-nodes` to create *private.key* without encryption

useful: **lock down *private.key***

- { add HTTP server to *ssl-cert* group }
- `sudo chown root:ssl-cert private.key` - **ch**ange **own**er of *private.key* to *root* user, *ssl-cert* group
- `sudo chmod 640 private.key` - change access permissions of *private.key* to owner R/W, group R
- now, HTTP server should be able to start and read UNencrypted *private.key*

**Option A**

stronger security, yet when server restarts, have to **manually type in passphrase** for *encrypted-private.key*

**Option B**

medium security, and probably good balance between A/C

**Option C**

weaker security, yet NOT prompted for UNencrypted *private.key* passphrase

Comment: Nginx **can** read encrypted private keys since version 1.7.3, see: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file

Comment: What is the purpose of bringing nginx and its versions into the discussion? Also, (B) and (C) offer equivalent security (namely, filesystem ACLs). The problem you are describing is the *Unattended Key Storage Problem*, and its a problem without a solution. See Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf) book.

Comment: @jww the question asks "what is the _purpose_...". I considered the question's context (QnA for programmers), which I attempted to indicate via "however, I feel the purpose (for programmers) is because:". specifically regarding security.. may be a discussion for [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)