# what is default cipher for PEM format in OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

I generate key/cert using openssl

```
openssl.exe req -x509 -days 1000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

It prompts for a password. I guess that the password is used for key encryption. However I haven't specified any cipher. What cipher is used in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default cipher is `DES-EDE3-CBC`, which is three-key triple DES EDE in CBC mode.  You can see this in the source code file [req.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/req.c).

```
cipher=EVP_des_ede3_cbc();
```

If you are using an OpenSSL version compiled with the option `OPENSSL_NO_DES`, then the library will not encrypt the key by default.  This is the same behavior as if you pass the [-nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051655/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-nodes-argument-in-openssl/5087138#5087138) argument.

An easier way to figure this out is just to look at your key file.  It announces the cipher in the PEM header.

```
$ cat key.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,CAFD88DF2EF2EE81
...
```

Comment: There are no headers just `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`. But the source code explains a lot.

Comment: @Vladimir:  Good to know.  I guess the PEM header must depend on the OpenSSL version.

Comment: @fernandohur:  Updated to github repo.

Comment: Per Sep15'11: yes. OpenSSL has long supported 'legacy' algorithm-specific formats (BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY, BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY, BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY) which are optionally PB-encrypted using the PEM header, and the generic standard PKCS#8 formst which has two options: clear (BEGIN PRIVATE KEY) and encrypted within the ASN.1 (BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY). Displaying the latter with `openssl asn1parse` decodes from ASN.1 the pbe-algorithm and parameters (salt & count). From version 1.0.0 generic commands `req pkcs8 pkcs12 genpkey pkey` use PKCS#8 instead of legacy formats.