# Signed PDF verification in Origami with an Adobe PKCS#7 certificate

Tags: ruby, pdf, adobe, pkcs#7, origami

**Summarized and clarified:**

Using origami, extracting a certificate from a signed pdf (signed within e.g. Adobe Reader) I cannot verify the signature:

```
origami = Origami::PDF.read(File.open('/path/to/file.pdf', 'r'))
pdf_signature = origami.signature[:Contents]
cert = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(pdf_signature).certificates.first

origami.verify(trusted_certs: [cert]) #=> false
```

As far as I can tell, this should always be true. So maybe Adobe uses a different byte range that it takes a SHA of when signing the PDF? How do I get that verify to work?

If it's any help, after tiptoing through the changes on origami master, I was able to get the exact OpenSSL error from the storecontext: V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY - I presume it means from the X509::Store it sets up.

---

**Full background**

I'm trying to verify the digital signature of a PDF. Here's what I've got:

A PDF that I've signed using Adobe Acrobat (tried both Pro 10 and Reader DC)

The key was generated in Acrobat Pro, I have access to the .p12, or exporting as FDF, PKCS#7 or just "Certificate File". Have also tried loading this "Certificate File" via Apple's "Keychain Access" and exporting that as a .pem This gives the same result as `OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(File.read('/path/to/exported.p7c')).certificates.first.to_pem` which gives the same result as:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -inform der -in pkcs7file.p7c -out certificate.cer
```

So, I'm pretty sure I've extracted the certificate correctly.

Also, I can verify that exact same certificate is embedded in the PDF -

```
pdf_signature = origami.signature[:Contents]
OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(pdf_signature).certificates.first.to_pem #=> Same as above
```

With the Origami gem, I've tried loading the certificate and attempting verification:

```
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read('/path/to/pem.cer'))
Origami::PDF.read(File.open('/path/to/file.pdf', 'r')).verify(trusted_certs: [cert])
```

Origami's output confirms the document has been signed, but the `verify(..)` method returns false.

Note that working through the code from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984805/origami-openssl-error-while-validating-digital-signature-of-a-pdf-in-rails/54526938#54526938) works fine, but it only seems to work if you generate the X.509 keypair using openssl (e.g. the ruby-land bindings as per that code). Unfortunately I'm required to use the pre-existing Adobe-blessed signatures from the user's machines.

That said, aside from this I have very few restraints; I can ask the users to export their certificate in any other way that is useful to us (I can even run some simple code on their machines if necessary), though I mustn't transmit the private key in the procedure. I don't have to use Origami for the verification, but it does have to be a command accessible from ruby on an ubuntu server. The users are all running on Macs with reasonably up-to-date software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten a little further from my original issue, but not by much:

#### Certificates require the correct extensions

In the original code [from Harry Fairbanks' very useful answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526938/208769) the extensions are paramount:

```
extension_factory = OpenSSL::X509::ExtensionFactory.new
extension_factory.issuer_certificate = cert
extension_factory.subject_certificate = cert

cert.add_extension extension_factory.create_extension('basicConstraints', 'CA:TRUE', true)
cert.add_extension extension_factory.create_extension('keyUsage', 'digitalSignature,keyCertSign')
cert.add_extension extension_factory.create_extension('subjectKeyIdentifier', 'hash')
```

So... following the rest of that answer, if you save the certificate to a pemfile, *the extensions do not also get saved*.

I was able to create a PDF, sign it with Origami using the key I exported from Acrobat reader, and then do the following:

```
cert = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(pdf_signature).certificates.first

origami.verify(trusted_certs: [cert]) #=> false

## ... then run the extension factory snippet above

origami.verify(trusted_certs: [cert]) #=> true
```

Success! In fact, even Adobe Acrobat Reader was happy - which I couldn't get it to do with the self-signed certificate that Origami generated.

... however, when I sign the document using Adobe Acrobat Reader, with the same key, perform the same magical incantation on the cert, I still get `false` from the verify call.

---

Note: I have been told that this actually works for some people. Not sure why it failed for me - when I have a chance to play, will give it another go. Will mark this as answered for now!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the ciphers are different. It could be that the Adobe cipher is not the same one that the openssl is using and would then fail the verification check. Take a look at this. [Details on ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402230/what-is-default-cipher-for-pem-format-in-openssl)

This might be useful too [openssl commands](https://gist.github.com/webtobesocial/5313b0d7abc25e06c2d78f8b767d4bc3)

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I suspect you might be talking about something else, so I've summarised my question for clarity. I'm pretty sure I've extracted the public key correctly, and according to Adobe Reader `Signature was created using Acrobat Reader 2019.021.20049 / Hash Algorithm: SHA256 / Signature algorithm: RSA with PKCS#1 v.1.5` So the question is, will Origami not verify this correctly?

Comment: Checking what Acrobat reader says, I signed a document using origami and the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526938/208769 - aside from `Signature was created using Adobe Reader 11.0.8` everything else about hash / signature algorithm is identical. So I don't think ciphers are the solution :(