# How to get key.pem and crt.pem from .pfx certificate in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I need to use `cURL` to access services to a resource using a certificate. I have only `.pfx` file. For `cURL` need two .pem file: `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` and `CURLOPT_SSLCERT`, like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
----------------------------------
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, './cert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, './key.pem');
----------------------------------
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

How do I get `key.pem` and `cert.pem`  from single `.pfx` file?

Comment: It's not duplicate! **Answer is here:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099201/how-to-convert-pfx-to-crt-and-pem-using-php/

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered.
Here's a link to the answer - it's what I used for my solution (same situation as yours)

[Converting PFX to PEM using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl)