# How to convert PFX to CRT and PEM using PHP?

Tags: php, openssl, certificate

How can I convert .pfx (PKCS12 or .p12) certificate to .crt and .pem using PHP OpenSSL functions, so I avoid commandline tools, which are not allowed on my public server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$res = [];
$openSSL = openssl_pkcs12_read($pkcs12, $res, $cert_password);
if(!$openSSL) {
    throw new ClientException("Error: ".openssl_error_string());
}
// this is the CER FILE
file_put_contents('CERT.cer', $res['pkey'].$res['cert'].implode('', $res['extracerts']));

// this is the PEM FILE
$cert = $res['cert'].implode('', $res['extracerts']);
file_put_contents('KEY.pem', $cert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use open the **OpenSSL** functions provided by PHP:

```php
$pathPfxCertificate  = "foo/bar/certificate.pfx";

$passwordCertificate = "123456";

// Attempt to read the PKCS12 certificate file using OpenSSL
$certificateStoreData = [];
$readedSuccessful = openssl_pkcs12_read(
    file_get_contents($pathPfxCertificate), 
    $certificateStoreData, 
    $passwordCertificate
);

if ($readedSuccessful == false) {
    throw new \Exception("Error: " . openssl_error_string());
}

// We read the data provided by `openssl_pkcs12_read` and assemble the content of the PEM certificate.
$contentPemCertificate = $certificateStoreData["pkey"];
$contentPemCertificate .= $certificateStoreData["cert"];
$contentPemCertificate .= ($certificateStoreData["extracerts"][1] ?? "");
$contentPemCertificate .= ($certificateStoreData["extracerts"][0] ?? "");

file_put_contents("foo/bar/certificate.pem", $contentPemCertificate);
```

**Documentation:**

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-pkcs12-read.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php