# How to use ssl client certificate (p12) with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, client-certificates, pkcs#12

I need to use client certificate file in format **p12**(PKCS12) to talk to a webserver with scrapy, is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't offer you a tested and complete solution here, but I know a few places where some adjustments might give you what you need.

The starting point is scrapy's `ContextFactory` object which defines the SSL/TLS configuration. The standard implementation `ScrapyClientContextFactory` doesn't use client certificates and also doesn't do any server certificate verification, it just accepts any certificate. ([More details](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-clientcontextfactory))

When looking into the [source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py#L83)  however you see the alternative `BrowserLikeContextFactory` is creating an `optionsForClientTLS` object.

This object can also take a `clientCertificate` parameter to authenticate to the server. ([Details](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/api/twisted.internet.ssl.optionsForClientTLS.html))

So in theory you need to subclass `BrowserLikeContextFactory`, write there your own `creatorForNetloc` method and make it create `optionsForClientTLS` that also have a `clientCertificate`

In a gist:

```
@implementer(IPolicyForHTTPS)
class ClientCertContextFactory(BrowserLikeContextFactory):

    def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        with open('yourcert.pem') as keyAndCert:
            myClientCert = twisted.internet.ssl.PrivateCertificate.load(keyAndCert.read())
        return optionsForClientTLS(hostname.decode("ascii"),
                                   trustRoot=platformTrust(),
                                   clientCertificate=myClientCert,
                                   extraCertificateOptions={
                                        'method': self._ssl_method,
                                   })
```

Activating the context factory in `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY = 'your.package.ClientCertContextFactory'
```

According to the docs `twisted.internet.ssl.PrivateCertificate` can only load pem or asn.1 format keys, means you will have to convert your key into pem format:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out client_ssl.pem -clcerts
```

(Borrowed from [Converting pfx to pem using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl))

**Update** Conversion for PKCS12 files in p12 format:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client_cert.p12 -out client_cert.pem -clcerts
```