# Send .pfx file with the api request

Tags: php, curl, certificate, pfx

This is my first time working on something this complex. I'm working on a project where the service that provides the API requests authentication using certificate. The certificate is in .pfx file.

Below is the code that's I'm currently working with

```
$url = 'https://api.example.com/sign';
$json = '{  
    "DateAndTimeOfIssue":"2017-08-31T13:28:02.433Z",
    "CashierName":"John",
    "TransType":"Sale",
    "PaymentType":"Card",
    "InvoiceNumber":"31082017-2",
    "ReferentDocumentNumber":null,
    "PAC":"KJ9UG3"
 }';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cert/9SSZJACN.pfx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'KJ9UG3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if( !$result ){
    echo "Curl Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo "Success: ". $result;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

With the above code, I'm getting the error message

> Curl Error: could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error
>   error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line, (no key found,
>   wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)

I have test the request using Postman and everything works great. Please advise what am I doing wrong over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert your file to a PEM file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out client_ssl.pem -clcerts

openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out root.pem -cacerts
```

see [Converting pfx to pem using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl)