# Python3.5 openssl error when validating certificate

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am having an issue trying to verify the certificate.  Looking at the python3 documentation it appears that I am doing everything correctly.

```
import requests
requests.get('example.com/token',cert('/myfile.pfx','mypasscode'))
```

I am also using `OpenSSL 1.0.2p` and `TLS 1.2`.  The server does not allow lower than `1.2`.

I am getting the following error `OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'PEM lib')]`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Your title suggests that it is about validating the certificate but the error is about using a local pfx file as certificate. In any case, you need to use PEM files.

Comment: I am probably using the incorrect terminology.  However I am trying to connect to `example.com/token` to receive an token.  I have managed to do this in perl using the `lwp` module.  `my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new ( ssl_opts => {  SSL_cert_file => $certfile, SSL_passwd_cb => sub {$pass},  SSL_cipher_list => '', });`  I was trying to achieve the same using python

Comment: In this case the duplicate fits your question. PFX is supported in newer versions of IO::Socket::SSL in Perl. In Python you need to use PEM though. See [Converting pfx to pem using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl) for how to convert the PFX.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to do the converting.  I wasn't sure because I don't do network programming but am learning on the fly.