# Dealing with .pfx certificate in Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

is there a way in loadrunner where we can use .pfx certificate? I know web_set_certificate_ex() only accepts .pem as a format. but what if the application server is not accepting .pem format and only .pfx format. is there any provision where in we can use .pfx?

Answer (score 0):

See Virtual User Guide, Advanced topics, creating virtual users with visual studio.

Once you have access to a full development environment you can use even the client source, along with whatever certificate model you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to convert between different formats via openssl tools. I found more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl).