# Elasticsearch crashes with PEM certificate error when using pfx split into separate certificate and key

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, certificate, keystore, pem

> [ERROR][c.a.o.s.s.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore] [example.com]
> Your keystore or PEM does not contain a key. If you specified a key
> password, try removing it. If you did not specify a key password,
> perhaps you need to if the key is in fact password-protected. Maybe
> you just confused keys and certificates.

Given a machine certificate example.pfx I can extract the key and certificate into two separate files
example-certificate.pem
example-certificate-key.pem
using the below commands from [Converting pfx to pem using openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl)

Extracts the private key form a PFX to a PEM file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in example.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem
```

Exports the certificate (includes the public key only):

```
openssl pkcs12 -in example.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out example-certificate.pem
```

Removes the password from the extracted private key as elasticsearch does not support passwords on the private key:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out example-certificate-key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the key to a pkcs8 syntax.

```
> openssl pkcs8 -in example-certifate-key.pem -topk8 -nocrypt -out example-certificate-key-pkcs8.pem
```

sourced from here.

https://superuser.com/questions/1297739/openssl-convert-pem-to-pfx-using-rsa-private-key