# Accessing external url from AWS ECS with https cert in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, https, certificate, amazon-ecs

Anybody know how to do this? I have a external client webservice outside of our aws cluster that requires https and for us to send a cert to authenticate our request.

In Postman for example, I added the pfx as a client cert and the requests started working. Now I just need to replicate this in my java service and in ECS. What is the best way to do this?

I have a few ideas, perhaps storing the cert in s3, and just adding it to my https each time I want to call that external api. There also is amazon certificate manager, but I am not sure if this will allow me to reference that cert when calling that external api. I also thought about just adding it to the java cert folder when we build the application for deployment.

ECS hosts will spin up and tear down based on demand, so I don't think I can just use keystore to add it to it since that instance of the server may not be there forever. I am using spring in my app if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely store the cert in an SSL bucket. Or you could store it in AWS Secrets Manager. Either of these would allow you to store the cert file encrypted, and you could have an S3 bucket policy or Secrets Manager resource policy that controls who has access to it. Also, either of these would allow you to manage the certificate easily through the AWS Web console. Secrets Manager has an advantage over S3 in that you can configure ECS to provide the content of the secret as an environment variable in your ECS container, so that you can access it without writing any code yourself to pull the value from Secrets Manager.

You could copy it to an EFS volume that you mount to your ECS service, and then your Java code could read it like a local file at run time. However any time you needed to manage the certificate file, you would need to spin up an EC2 server that also has the EFS volume mounted so that you can perform file copy commands into the volume. The file wouldn't be able to be managed through the AWS web console.

You mention simply copying the file into your docker image when you build it, and that can absolutely be an acceptable method of providing your ECS app with the certificate file. One disadvantage is that the file would always need to be present on the server where you are building the docker image, which may be a problem if you are using a CI/CD system to build your images.

I've seen client certificates provided to ECS apps in all the above listed ways (S3, Secrets Manager, EFS volumes, and built directly into the docker container).

Amazon Certificate Manager is geared more towards storing certificates that you will be attaching to load balancers, CloufFront distributions, etc, not client-side certificates like the one you are using here. I think you could use it for your purpose, but it isn't really designed for that so I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thats the impression I got with amazon certificate manager. How do you store a file in secret manager? I haven't used it, we use system manager parameter store to store our secrets (passwords and api keys but never a file). The system manager parameter store allows us to it as a secure string. Can we also store a file here, or would it need to be stored in secret manager? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You would just copy/paste the contents of the file into Secrets Manager. You can't store a "file" in Secrets Manager, you would just store the contents of the file as a secret string. You might be able to do the same with Parameter Store. SSM Parameter store has a 4KB limit, Secrets Manager has a 10KB limit.

Comment: when I open the .pfx file in notepad, it contains non human readable characters (the stuff you'd see in a jpg or something). How can I possibly paste the contents of this file into a string?

Comment: You would need to convert it to .pem format first, before storing it in Secrets Manager or Parameter Store.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try that, any tools you recommend to do this?

Comment: OpenSSL is the standard tool for this sort of thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413646/converting-pfx-to-pem-using-openssl

Comment: I decided to just go the route of getting the file into s3 and referencing it in the code. I couldn't get java to ingest a stringified version of the cert.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it "stringified". It's converted to a different key format. You would have to do something like this to load it into Java https://www.baeldung.com/java-read-pem-file-keys